# What will happen when I set a proxy for HttpClient object?

Tags: java, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to get the idea of setting up a proxy for HttpClient object. I found below code regarding that.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("proxy.com", 80, "http");
DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner)
                .build();
```

And below code,

```
/**
* How to send a request via proxy.
*
* @since 4.0
*/
public class ClientExecuteProxy {

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try {
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("httpbin.org", 443, "https");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("127.0.0.1", 8080, "http");

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setProxy(proxy)
                .build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/");
        request.setConfig(config);

        System.out.println("Executing request " + request.getRequestLine() + " to " + target + " via " + proxy);

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}

}
```

Can somebody explain why we need to specify a proxy like this for HttpClient objects and how the HttpClient object behave in both these scenarios ?

Answer (score 1):

You need HTTP proxy to connect to the INTERNET. Its similar to web browser proxy setting where in order to access certain networks you need to configure proxy.

To mimic the same with the HTTPClient api calls or any Java URL call, proxy details has to be provided in the call object. 
Here is what happens with the call is made:
 1. The URL submit is done to the proxy instead of the intended host.
 2. Proxy then connects to the intended URL.

This is the forward proxy scenario (there is sometimes reverse proxy as well) and all the network requests are routed through a proxy. Here proxy is not visible to the ongoing network calls.

The above two examples sets proxy in httpclient object first one uses builder pattern and second one is a step by step execution to set proxy within httpclient. Both seems to perform same.

In my opinion you still need to configure Java level proxy details by setting JVM proxy options.

Comment: Thanks for the response. "In my opinion you still need to configure Java level proxy details by setting JVM proxy options." can you please elaborate this statement.

Comment: You can set the VM proxy details like: 
-Dhttp.proxyHost=hostname  
-Dhttp.proxyPort=port